# Different program behavior when removing superfluous parallel statement

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I just got stuck while trying to find the data race in the lower code:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    #pragma omp for 
    for(i=0; i<m; i++) {
        y[i]=0;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            y[i]=y[i]+A[i][j]*x[j];
        }
    }
}
```

I get different results for y. Bizarrely, everything seems to be fine when adding `parallel` in front of `for`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

I thought this keyword would be superfluous here because there is already a parallel block. Why does the program behave differently when removing the keyword?

Comment: Well, all I can see there is that `j` appears to be declared outside of the parallel region, and is shared among all threads. Try using `for(int j...`. I'm not sure if `i` also has that problem.

Comment: You're right. I forget to declare `j` private. Apparently I was sitting to long in front of my code and just oversaw it. `i` doesn't need to  be explicitly declared private as the loop variable of a parallelized loop is declared private implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a parallel Block nested in a parallel Block, it would be ignored, if you do not activate "nested parallelism" f.e. with
    `omp_set_nested(1);`
So with the `#pragma omp parallel for` your code will executed with all Threads and all Threads do the same calculations.

If you make a `#pragma omp for` in a parallel Block, it will not be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

In your inner `for` loop, the value of `y[i]` is changes across parallel executions and being used both as target and a source.

Comment: No, this is not the reason. `y[i]` never points to the same memory location in multiple threads. There are no threads that share the same `i`.